# docker build from inside container

Tags: python, docker, build

I'm trying to build a docker image from inside a container using the Python docker SDK. The build command

`client.build(dockerfile="my.Dockerfile", path=".", tag="my-tag")`

fails with

`OSError: Can not read file in context: /proc/1/mem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that docker cannot build from the container's root directory, which was implicit due to the build context `path='.'`. This can easily be fixed by using a working directory in the Dockerfile of the container performing the build operation, e.g.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
RUN apt-get update -y
WORKDIR my-workdir        <-- ADD TO FIX
COPY . .
CMD python -m my-script
```